# Creating Telegram Bot on RaspberryPi

Tags: raspbian, python

I am trying to create Telegram Bot on my raspberry pi 3

```
import telepot
bot=telepot.Bot('*tokenhere*')
bot.getMe()
```

After this i am getting telepot.exception.UnauthorizedError with error code 401. Is it saying token is not correct?

Comment: Just for clarity.. you did replace '*tokenhere*' with a valid token?

Comment: @ppumkin yes I have replaced it with token which i have got after creating a bot using BotFather

Comment: For those who are facing the same issue please use below link   https://api.telegram.org/bot123456:ABC-DEF1234ghIkl-zyx57W2v1u123ew11/getMe  and replace token with your token. This worked for me. source: Telegram Bot API

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow all of the steps in [How do I Create a Bot](https://core.telegram.org/bots#3-how-do-i-create-a-bot)?

From the website:

> 3. How do I create a bot?
>      There's a… bot for that. Just talk to [BotFather](https://telegram.me/botfather) (described [below](https://core.telegram.org/bots#botfather) in 6.) and follow a few simple steps. Once you've created a bot and received your authorization token, head down to the [Bot API manual](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) to see what you can teach your bot to do.
>      You may also like to check out some code examples [here »](https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples)

The website goes on to describe `BotFather`

> 6. BotFather
>
> BotFather is the one bot to rule them all. It will help you create new bots and change settings for existing ones.
>
> **Create a new bot**
>   Use the `/newbot` command to create a new bot. The BotFather will ask you for a name and username, then generate an authorization token for your new bot.
>
> The name of your bot will be displayed in contact details and elsewhere.
>
> The Username is a short name, to be used in mentions and telegram.me links. Usernames are 5-32 characters long and are case insensitive, but may only include Latin characters, numbers, and underscores. Your bot's username must end in ‘bot’, e.g. ‘tetris_bot’ or ‘TetrisBot’.
>
> The token is a string along the lines of `110201543:AAHdqTcvCH1vGWJxfSeofSAs0K5PALDsaw` that will be required to authorize the bot and send requests to the Bot API.
>
> **Generate an authorization token for your bot**
>   If your existing token is compromised or you lost it for some reason, use the `/token` command to generate a new one.
>
> **Edit settings**
>   The remaining commands are pretty self-explanatory:

It then goes on to explain the remaining commands.

Comment: Could you please list an outline of those steps here.

Comment: @John Burger I have received a token and used it to test account   bot=telepot.Bot('*tokenhere*')
bot.getMe() #after this line i am getting unauthorized Error as I have mentioned in my question. Do I need to generate another token and check?

Comment: @DarthVader you can find those steps here http://www.instructables.com/id/Set-up-Telegram-Bot-on-Raspberry-Pi/

Comment: Does the token 'look' like the one in the example? Not exactly, of course, but with the same number of characters etc? And you _are_ using `https` to connect, yes?

Comment: @JohnBurger yes token look like one in the example and same number of characters. I am not sure about using https connection, How can I make sure that it is using https.

Comment: The `'telepot'` library for Python does a lot of the work for you. Are you using Telepot 8.1? You seem to be doing the right things at the beginning of your question. But you need to work through everything on https://github.com/nickoala/telepot - scroll down to the section called "Basics"

Comment: @JohnBurger I am not sure about the version when I have installed but I have upgraded telepot and I have followed basics from the link above and after test account instead of "{u'username': u'YourBot', u'first_name': u'Your Bot', u'id': 123456789}" I am getting error.

Comment: It may very well be that the website is down. I have had no luck accessing it for the last few minutes. One of those things!

Comment: @JohnBurger post a comment here if you were able to go through this. Thanks for the information